# Eclipse for java developers

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem with eclipse (for java developers). I try to do an app, but when i select a java file and i click "run", Eclipse give me this error. I rename my app "AndroidFAQ". So, it appear this problem:

"AndroidFAQ does not specify a `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` instrumentation or does not declare uses-library `android.test.runner` in its `AndroidManifest.xml`".

Comment: Post code instead. Post your Manifest File and your activities.

Comment: `I rename my app "AndroidFAQ"` is this your error? Or what?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. You may want to add more information (and possibly code) about this error, so that people can help you find the problem.

Comment: Excuseif I wrote something wrong... I don't know how add more information and code about this error... where are these errors, and these codes ? i want post a screenshot... so it would be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the `AndroidManifest.xml` the following -

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="..." android:label="..." />

<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Hope this helps.

---

Updated.

You can create a test project that its root directory `tests/` was at the same level as the `src/` directory in the main project. You can also create a new test project. This new project should have an explicit dependency on your main project. The wizard will create this and set it up correctly at the time you create the original project (if you click the checkbox)

```
 +Hello Android
 | |
 | +----+src
 | |    |
 | ...  |-+my.pkg.app
 |      |  |
 |      |  +-MainClass.java
 |      |
 |     ...
 |    
 |- AndroidManifest.xml
 ...
 |
 + Hello Android Test
 | |
 | +----+src
 | |    |
 | ...  +--+my.pkg.app.test
 |      |  |
 |    ...  +-MainTest.java
 |         |
 |        ... 
 |
 |- AndroidManifest.xml
 ...
```

In this case `AndroidManifest.xml` file should look like as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.pkg.app.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="my.pkg.app"
        android:label="Tests for my.pkg.app"/>
</manifest>
```

See also:

- [Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)

Comment: I tried... But i don't know what i must write in android:targetPackage="..." android:label="..." />. I tried a lot, but eclipse give me an error...

Comment: Excuse me... but can you be more precise? Because i am a beginner... and i'm not english... So what i must put in "android:targetPackage=" and "android:label="? if i can talk you in private, because so i can send you a screenshot... thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks so much ... I tried but I do not work the same ... When I write what you told me tells me that there is an error in the XML ...